# perform MINUS operation in MySQL not working

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT m.inv_id,m.cus_id,CONCAT(c.customer_name ,', ', c.address) AS address,d.item_id,p.prod_name,d.quantity
FROM invoice_m m INNER JOIN customers c INNER JOIN invoice_d d INNER JOIN products p
WHERE m.cus_id = c.customer_id
AND m.inv_id = d.inv_id
AND d.item_id = p.prod_id
AND m.inv_id = 3
minus
SELECT m.inv_id,m.cus_id,m.cus_addr AS address,d.item_id,d.item_name AS prod_name,d.out_qty AS quantity 
FROM delivery_m m INNER JOIN delivery_d d 
WHERE m.inv_id = 3
```

i am trying to perform MySQL minus query not working.I need to minus (qty - out_qty ) so that i can get actual qty.

Comment: Could you please provide more information on any errors you get.

Comment: What's a MySQL minus query?

Comment: Confusingly, I can see that there's a whole MySQL tutorial on a concept that doesn't even exist in MySQL. You have to wonder sometimes.

Comment: @MoonMoo , i  am trying to perform MySQL minus query not working.I need to minus (qty - out_qty ) so that i can get actual qty.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL doesn’t support  MINUS set operators.

so a query like

```
  SELECT x, y FROM table_a
  MINUS
  SELECT x, y FROM table_b;
```

In MySQL became:

```
SELECT a.x, a.y
FROM table_a a LEFT JOIN table_b b
ON a.x = b.x AND a.y = b.y
WHERE b.x IS NULL;
```

Comment: i am trying to minus qty and out qty . So that i can get actual qty. any options

Comment: And how do you do a MINUS for quite huge queries with subqueries? Building this up again? Seems counter-intuitive.

Comment: @MattSom  .. your comment is not clear to  me .. eventually try add  a proper question with code and data sample and comment me the related  link